# Linearity of the supremum

Tags: real-analysis, summation, supremum-and-infimum

> In which cases does the following hold:
>   Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions, then
>   $$\sup_{k\in \mathbb N}\left(\sum_{n}^if_k(n)\right)
> =\sum_{n}^i \sup_{k\in \mathbb N}f_k(n).$$

I guess if the $f_k(n)$ are always positive?
When I can swap the supremum and the summation when I deal with infinite sums?

Comment: You need to be much more precise with your index of summation ==> what is the index? From which value is in starting, what is the ending value...

Comment: -- Hardly ever.

Comment: Why wasn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, let's say you have a finite set of functions $f_k$, $k = 1 \ldots K$, and a finite set of $n$'s, $n=1..N$, and you want

$$ \sup_{k=1 \ldots K}\sum_{n=1}^N f_k(n) = \sum_{n=1}^N \sup_{k=1\ldots K} f_k(n) \tag{1}$$
Note that you always have $$f_j(n) \le \sup_{k=1\ldots K} f_k(n)\tag{2}$$ so
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N f_j(n) \le \sum_{n=1}^N \sup_{k=1\ldots K} f_k(n) \tag{3}$$
and therefore
$$ \sup_{k=1\ldots K}\sum_{n=1}^N f_k(n) \le \sum_{n=1}^N \sup_{k=1\ldots K} f_k(n) \tag{4}$$
Moreover, in order to have equality in (4), you need equality in (3) for some $j$, and that in turn requires equality in (2) for all $n$.  That is, the 
necessary and sufficient condition is that there is some $j$ where the maximum is attained for all $n$.

An infinite set of $n$'s doesn't change anything, as long as the sums always converge.

For an infinite set of $k$'s, things can be rather more complicated.